# ASP.NET login looks different when I debug and deploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I was just curious if anyone might know why this suddenly changed on me.

I've been working on this for over a month, and it has never happened. My login screen in Visual Studio looks like the default screen (which I want it to, and it always has) when I'm working on it, but when I deploy it looks bland with just normal text (never happened before) .

It seems like it'd probably be something simple I'm overlooking, but any insight would be greatly appreciated. Picture one is what it looks like in VS, the way I want it to look, and picture 2 is what it looks like when I debug/deploy.

[image: The way I want it to look, and the way it looks in VS.]

[image: The way I don't want it to look, and the way it looks when deployed.]

Comment: check whether your CSS files are loaded

Comment: any css files you are missing?I suppose Account Information is a panel, and it loses its outline, that is a problem I am having, too.

Comment: Sounds like you're stylesheets aren't being applied.

Comment: I checked my css files first, and everything seemed to be there, so I was unsure where to go from there.

Comment: No, it happens in other browsers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your CSS files are in a folder that's only accessible to logged in users.  Try adding a [location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) to your web.config file:

```
<location path="Your Styles Folder" allowOverride="false">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Oh man, that would actually make complete sense.. I'll try that out now.

Comment: This code didn't work only because I had <deny users="?"/> for everything, but once I removed that it went back to normal. So that is the problem, but can I have <deny users="?"/> for everything with the exception of the css?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind! I figured it out! Thank you so much for the help! Such a simple problem I probably would have never figured out.

Comment: @Kruce: No problem.  That one got me when I was first starting out, too  ;)

Comment: can you give some example of the location path, because I still fail to do that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you other `css` has `tables` and they are `overriding` them.Try to remove them and it will work fine.