# CSS not being applied for ASP.NET MVC app deployed on IIS

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

```
Environment:
Visual Studio 2013 
ASP.NET MVC 5 
Windows 8.1 (both dev and deployment server)
```

My app displays and executes as expected within Visual Studio environment using localhost.

However, when I deploy to my IIS server, I find two problems (maybe related so including both here).

```
Installed as an app on the default site and accessed via http://myMachineName/myApp
1. Page doesn't render correctly. Everything is on the page, but the CSS is not being applied.
2. The code behind does NOT execute.


Installed as a new site and accessed via its port number: http://myMachineName:81
1. Page doesn't render correctly. Everything is on the page, but the CSS is not being applied.
2. The code behind does execute correctly.
```

Comment: Check browser's developer tool and see if your css file is loading

Comment: do you have the path correctly in the routing? Do you have the inetpub localhost added? is the css i nthe source path correctly?

Comment: @Zaki How do I do this and what am I looking for? (I'm using IE on Windows 8)

Comment: in IE : press F12 go to network tab and click on run, and refresh...

Comment: @Zaki It looks like CSS is being loaded/applied, but the look and feel is definitely different between the app run locally and the app run from IIS. Why would it behave/look different?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to each page fixed the UI and functionality issues on IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

have had the same problem. turned out that it was a setting related to static content in IIS.

here is the link to the answer:
[CSS, Images, JS not loading in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis)