# Static resources not loading on ASP site

Tags: html, asp.net, http-status-code-404, iis-6

could someone tell me why my bootstrap site is not working on all devices?

When I view it from my computer it looks fine. When I view it from a co-workers computer it looks like all css is striped and its not using boot strap, same with when I view it from my iphone 5.

Here is the head of my master page

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Flashpoint P.O.S.</title>

    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="../Content/Styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#navList').height() + 10);


        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#navList').height() + 10);

        });


    });


</script>


</head>
```

[Here is the link to the broken site](http://easystoremanager.com/TrimPOS2/User/Home.aspx)

EDIT: I just noticed it works fine in firefox, but not in Chrome on production environment. (Posted link)

But it works in both in development environment (ms vs 2010)

Another Odd thing, I can navigate to http://easystoremanager.com/Trim/Images/contactus.jpg on firefox but not chrome?

Any ideas?

Comment: You're getting 404 errors on all your external resources.

Comment: @isherwood What would cause this? Invalid virtual directory or permissions?

Comment: @isherwood  Do you have the same issue in my edit? Can navigate to the contact us picture in firefox but not chrome?

Comment: I don't get anything besides a custom errors page.  How are you sure your getting 404's?

Comment: The first answer here fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis