# Images not showing on localhost for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, localhost

There are a ton of articles about this, but none of the answers are working for me.  I am simply trying to view an image on localhost (    http://localhost/MySite/images/logo.jpg).  The browser just shows a white page with only a html shell. View source shows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

 <META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
 <BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Things I have tried:

1 - Tools, Options, Advanced, Show Images

2 - Add Role, Web Server, Common HTTP Features, Static Content

3 - Verify path is correct

4 - web.config -

`<location path="images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>`

Please help!

edit - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, ASP.NET v2.0, Web Site

Comment: The view source tells us the image is not being rendered by asp.net. Can you show us your code?

Comment: There is no code for this page.  I am simply trying to view the image in the browser http://localhost/MySite/images/logo.jpg.

Comment: I found the answer [Here][1].  Scroll down the to post by Moiz Tankiwala.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis