# unable to load some css and js in my ASP.NET project with Bundlification

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

```
//My BundleConfig.cs look like-
public class BundleConfig
{        
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryUI").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                  "~/Scripts/CustomAutocomplete.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/JqueryUI/jquery-ui.css"));            
    }
}

//In cshtml file calls like-

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

While running project in visual studio it works fine but after deploying on server some css and js files are not loads correctly
I have also done IIS settings as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis)
after deploy webpage looks like
[image: after deploy webpage looks like]

But webpage should look like this
[image: But webpage should look like this]

Please provide solution...

Comment: Is your .NET installation same locally and  on hosting? Bundling requires minimum ASP.NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: Yes i used ASP.NET 4.5 framework and installation is locally on hosting..

Comment: To me it looks like you have missed a `css` file as the screenshots are pretty similar apart from some styling

Comment: How does the generated HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem in your `IIS` setting.If you use Windows PC go

`Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Programs and Features`

then in left side click `Turn Windows Features on or off`.

after then go `Internet Information Services>World wide web service>Common HTTP Features` and checked `Static Content` and click `ok` for apply changes.

after this change successfully restart you PC.

If you use Windows server setting all most same.

**As per Update your Question**

After publishing you miss some `CSS`.You can fiend which you missing by `inspect element` in your browser.and add them into correct location.

**cause:** when you add the file some how then file properties (`Build Action` not set into `content`)

**solution :** So fiend which files you missing and go to `visual studio` and right click on those file and go to `properties` and set `Build Action=content`.

Hopefully it's help for you.