# iis not showing image of asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While testing in visual studio all work good, but when I am deployed in iis it doesn't show image what's the cause of a problem? even when i test it on iis express through WebMatrix it work but not worked in iis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS, Images, JS not loading in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis)

Comment: Is the folder where your images are stored included in your publish?

Comment: When deployed under IIS, load the page in browser and then right click on the broken image and click `open in new tab` and check if image path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **Static Content** feature is installed on the Web Server under the Role Services of IIS ---> Common HTTP Features.

The problem may be that IIS is not serving Static Content, check this link:
http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/11/iis-7-not-loading-css-and-image/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<img src= "@Url.Content("~/path/img")">
```