# ASP.NET and IIS with SSL doesn't returns all files because forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've just add to my site a `SSL` certificate and setup `IIS` to redirect all requests to `https`. After that I have a lot of issues with the site because the browser shows errors like

> HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

This error is mainly for `JavaScript` files and images. Here a screenshot of `Microsoft Edge DevTools`.

[image: DevTools Microsoft Edge]

I googled a bit and some people complained because `Microsoft Edge` doesn't work properly. Then I tried with `Firefox` and I noticed another strange thing: the site is working fine but there are a lot of `403` in the Developer Tools`.

[image: Firefox Developer Tools]

I tried to add in the `web.config` a generic authorization for all users to the Scripts folder. Nothing changed.

```
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Do you have any helps?

Comment: SSL is not about authorization but secure access of resources. So, Now you cannot call the resources whether images or js by http call since they are now only accessed by https.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. As you can see, all resources have an `https` url. In my page I'm using for example `~/Scripts`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403: FORBIDDEN could be caused due to number of reasons. You may need to try below options if any of these worked or causing issue:

1) Check if it is coming in all the browser.

2) Clear Cache and Cookies of the browser and then try again.

3) Check for Content Security Policy for safe access of resources

4) Check for file permissions in your wwwroot folder

5) More you can check in below link ....

[CSS, Images, JS not loading in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis)