# IIS Windows Server 2012 - Production Website not loading CSS, Images or JS because of bundle/access issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I've developed an ASP.NET 4.5 website and ran it successfully on localhost.

When deploying it to IIS and viewing the website the CSS/JS/Images failed to load. The console showed:

[image]

Note I am using Bundle Config to load these files. E.g in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/animate")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/lightbox")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/nice-select")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/owl-carousel")

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/stellar")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lightbox")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/nice-select")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/isotope")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/owl-carousel")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/animate")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/flipclock")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/theme")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I enabled static content on IIS as well as set Anonymous Authentication to true which the [sister question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis?rq=1) answer used

[image]

I do not know what else to do.

I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to Enable `Directory Browsing` located in your IIS

`Features View`

Check also the `user rights` of all folders deployed or to that `specific folder`. If you have a full access into it.

Right Click the project folder and `Properties`.

Check also the `application pool` => `Advance Settings` =>`Enable-32-Bit Application` == `true or false`;

You can choose as default to 32 bit

Or is your files are included to the deployment server?

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

would you please check the static resource folder has granted access to IIS and Application Pool user? `Network` and `Network Service` account would be accountable for IIS
Next step you can check if you have denied Anonymous access in Authorization Rules(Not Authentication)