# Local IIS treating Framework ASP.NET as Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-10

I'm having the static content issue where I get 404s on images and CSS. I've gone through all the [standard fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis/21718881#21718881).

One thing I found was that moving my Git repo into the wwwroot folder, worked. My coworker said this was how Core apps were done. I had installed Core to work on a separate application a month or two back, and it always worked fine. But then when I went back to the Framework 4.6.1 ASP.NET app, it no longer worked locally for debugging. If I publish to a server, it's fine.

I have since uninstalled VS 2017 Pro as well as everything Core related. Reinstalled VS with a coworkers config. Removed IIS feature from Windows, rebooted, added it back with all the same settings as my coworkers.

Does anyone know if there is some config VS is using that is confusing IIS into thinking my Framework webapp is Core?

IIS error:

```
 Module        IIS Web Core
 Notification  MapRequestHandler
 Handler       StaticFile
 Error Code    0x80070002
 Logon Method  Anonymous
 Logon User    Anonymous
```

Comment: what is the URL of your images when you debug?

Comment: What did you mean by "Framework webapp is Core"????? For ASP.NET Core MVC application, the default webroot is that `wwwroot` folder with the use of `app.UseStaticFiles()` inside `Configure` method. You can check out the page here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2