# The web server (IIS) fails to load static files (css, js, images) over HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, https, .net-5

I am hosting my website with a hosting service provider. The website loads perfectly when the request is **HTTP** (i.e. http://example.com), but the web server (IIS) fails to load static files (css, js, images) over **HTTPS** (i.e. https://example.com), I get "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403**".

I checked this link [CSS, Images, JS not loading in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis/38101217) and it says maybe I need to set the identity of the anonymous user to the App Pool Identity. The problem is that I asked my hosting service provider to perform that task, but the provider told me that they do not do that on application pool identity because this increases security leaks with impersonating authentication.

I am using .NET 5.0 and I tried to modify the *launchSettings.json* file to allow anonymousAuthentication, but that didn't work, do you know what else can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Set authentication with anonymous authentication may actually affect security, have you tried the answer in the post you provided which about windows permission ?

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen I did try the windows permission, but it didn't solved the issue. I am using a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate so I don't know if I am missing something.

Comment: I think you can [create](https://support.microsoft.com/) a support ticket for this, microsoft engineer will help find the root cause.

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen, I migrated the website to another hosting provider and the problem is gone, so I think it was the hosting firewall that caused the problem.

Comment: Ok, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize from the comments:

> The problem was caused by hosting firewall. Migrated the website to another hosting provider, then the problem is gone.